# Transfering rows of data from different files into a single R variable

Tags: r

I have six different files and they all have the same columns and there are more than 1,000,000 rows of combined data. I want to transfer all these rows into a single R variable.

Can I do it? Can you actually import data from several files into a R variable

Comment: Please read [**how to make a great reproducible example**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/1478381) and update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, yes you can. R is very versatile like that.

```
#  Get files
fls <- list.files( path = "C:/path/to/files/" , full.names = TRUE )

#  Read them in. Each is a list element
inTabs <- lapply( fls , read.table , h = TRUE , sep = "\t" )

#  Bind each together into a single data.frame
out <- do.call( rbind , inTabs )
```

Comment: @arbautjc you are right. The question is VERY lazy. And my initial offering answered the posed question in it's entirety. *Can you do it?*... *YES YOU CAN*.

Comment: Why the -1? This is a perfectly useful answer

Comment: @alexwhan check the revision history if possible. The first sentence was initially all I could be bothered to post because I felt *that* answered the question the OP asked. Then I felt a sense of remorse and community spirit and posted a minimal workable example.

Comment: Fair enough - totally understandable!

Comment: @alexwhan arguably what is more worrying is why the *upvote* on the question?! :-)

Comment: Done. I like spaces - I find it makes my code more readable.